# How to call an api from another api in fastapi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback, fastapi, starlette

I was able to get the response of one API from another but unable to store it somewhere(in a file or something before returning the response)
`response=RedirectResponse(url="/apiname/")` (I want to access a post request with header and body)

> I want to store this response content without returning it.

Yes, if I return the function I will get the results but when I print it I don't find results.
Also, if I give post request then I get error Entity not found.

I read the starlette and fastapi docs but couldn't get the workaround. The callbacks also didn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way to make downstream Https requests inside of Uvicorn/FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73721736/what-is-the-proper-way-to-make-downstream-https-requests-inside-of-uvicorn-fasta)

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556972/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71398460/17865804)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I didn't exactly get the way to store response without returning using **fastapi/starlette** directly. But I found a workaround for completing this task.

- For the people trying to implement same thing, Please consider this
  way.

```
import requests

def test_function(request: Request, path_parameter: path_param):

    request_example = {"test" : "in"}
    host = request.client.host
    data_source_id = path_parameter.id

    get_test_url= f"http://{host}/test/{id}/"
    get_inp_url = f"http://{host}/test/{id}/inp"

    test_get_response = requests.get(get_test_url)
    inp_post_response = requests.post(get_inp_url , json=request_example)
    if inp_post_response .status_code == 200:
        print(json.loads(test_get_response.content.decode('utf-8')))
```

> Please let me know if there are better approaches.

Comment: The docs discuss a different method here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/openapi-callbacks/#an-app-with-callbacks I like your answer b/c it keeps the call within the route that requires the call (e.g., for captcha-related verification this can be handy).

Answer (score 10):

I have the same problem & I needed to call the third-party API with **async** way
So I tried many ways & I came solution with [**requests-async** library](https://pypi.org/project/requests-async/)
and it works for me.

```
import http3

client = http3.AsyncClient()

async def call_api(url: str):

    r = await client.get(url)
    return r.text

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    ...
    result_1 = await call_api('url_1')
    result_2 = await call_api('url_2')
    ...
```

[httpx](https://pypi.org/project/httpx/) also you can use
[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBVb4IB3O_U&t=2662s) he is using httpx